# Date format in asp.net application

Tags: asp.net

How to retrieve date from a table and show in a gridview?
I am using ajaxtoolkit:calenderextender in which date format is MM/dd/yyyy because my server date format is MM/dd/yyyy. I am inserting date field into database using this command
`DateTime.Parse(txtvdate.Text).ToString("yyyyMMdd")`. Now I am trying to show it on grid view as MM/dd/yyyy.

aspx code:

```
<asp:BoundField DataField = "Vdate" HeaderText = "Tran Date" DataFormatString="{0:MM/dd/yyyy}" HtmlEncode="false" />
```

Comment: Use Convert.ToDateTime(yourstring) and I think that's what you need.

Comment: but how can i do it in gridview bound field

Comment: ... your date field in the database is... a string? Save it as DateTime.

Answer (score 0):

Here I provided a simple sample below:

If you have Date as string in database then cast it to Datetime:

```
Let us consider two columns X and Y:

 X       Y

 1     03/04/2014
 2     05/04/2014
```

**If Y column is string datatype in SQL database:**

while selecting from table using sql, cast the column y as Date if it's Datatype is string:

Casting in sql query use the below:

```
   CAST('your string date' as DATETIME)
```

For more details see the below link for casting and converting string to Datetime in SQL:

[Casting in SQL](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187928.aspx)

**Casting in Datatable:**

Datatable dt_first contains the columns X and Y as shown in the above table.

If Y is string then do the following:

```
DataTable dtcloned = dt_first.Clone();
            dtcloned.Columns[1].DataType=typeof(DateTime); ---> converts the datatype of Y column to Datetime
            foreach (DataRow row in dt_new.Rows)
            {
                dtcloned.ImportRow(row);
            }
```

**Bind the Cloned datatable to GridView:**

```
grid.DataSource = dtcloned;
grid.DataBind();
```

**Finally in BoundField of GridView:**

***Y should be DateTime DataType.***

```
 <asp:BoundField DataField="Y" HeaderText="Date" DataFormatString="{0:dd/MM/yyyy}" />
```

I think this will solve your problem.

Answer (score 0):

You can also check if you are using Template Field:

```
    <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="last_modified_date">
    <ItemTemplate>                           
        <asp:Label ID="lblModyDate" runat="server" Font-Size="10px" CssClass="ControlStyleUpperCase" 
          Text='<%# Bind("last_modified_date","{0:dd/MM/yyyy HH:mm:tt}") %>'></asp:Label>
    </ItemTemplate>
</asp:TemplateField>
```